# How can I include a .zip file in a .net (C++-CLI) assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, c++-cli, zip, embedded-resource

Is it possible to include a .zip file as a resource inside a .net assembly? and if so, how is it done and how do I access it?

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) might work to access the data in there? I've used this before to access images, but I seem to recall having to manually re-import the resource into visual studio to pick up changes. Is it possible to include the .zip at compile time?

**Edit (@Tejs)**

These are the options I have available if I right-click on the resource:

[image: First screen shot of options available]
[image: Second screen shot of options available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found something which seems to work:

### Step 1 - Embed the .zip

- Right-click on the project and go to properties
- Navigate to `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input`
- Add the path to the .zip file to the `Embed Managed Resource File` property. For my initial test case I added `$(ProjectDir)\ReadMe.zip` which was a zip of the readme file which visual studio creates when you make a new project.

### Step 2 - Extract the .zip

Add some code to extract that .zip file:

```
        Reflection::Assembly^ a1 = Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();

        cli::array<String^>^ names = a1->GetManifestResourceNames();
        for each( String^ name in names )
        {
            IO::BinaryReader^ s1 = gcnew IO::BinaryReader(a1->GetManifestResourceStream(name)); 

            String^ fileName = "Extracted_"+name;
            IO::BinaryWriter^ sw = gcnew IO::BinaryWriter( IO::File::Open( fileName, IO::FileMode::Create ) );
            sw->Write(s1->ReadBytes(s1->BaseStream->Length));
            sw->Flush();
            sw->Close();
        }
```

When that snippet runs, each .zip file added to the manifest at compile time will magically appear in the same directory the program was run from. I've tried modifying the contents of the .zip and sure enough, re-compiling adds the altered file into the executable and the result is extracted as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to mark the zip file as `Embedded Resource` under `Build Action`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx

Comment: I don't appear to have a build action. Under `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `Tool` I have the following options: `C/C++ Compiler Tool`, `Custom Build Tool`, `MIDL Tool`, `Resource Compiler Tool`, `Managed Resource Compiler`, `Web Service Proxy Generator`, `XML Data Proxy Generator` ...and no matter which of those I select it doesn't seem to bring up anything about embedded resources.

Comment: It's a property on the specific file. Right click the file in Solution Explorer, and hit properties.

Comment: I've added some screen shots to indicate the options I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the DotNetZip library source which is hosted at [CodePlex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).
They use a pre-build process to compress files into a .zip and embed this as a resource in the library to later access it (it contains stuff required for self-extracting archives).